How to resize and scale pages within Acrobat 9
I have a PDF containing technical drawings of my building, the pages were meant to be at 1:100 scale when printed at A3 or A1 size. The most original version of these drawings I have are in PDFs where all pages were printed at A4 size, meaning taking measurements from the drawings is quite difficult.
How can I, using Acrobat 9 or other free tools, resize the pages and contents in my PDF files to be correct?

@KJ - These drawings are of the building I'm technical manager for, I took over 2 years ago and the company that actually build the place has gone into administration since so these are the only real reference I have short of actually measuring the building myself. All the drawings to have "DO NOT SCALE" on them but when I had one of them printed at A1 it was within a couple percent of actual size, which is good enough for 95% of the work we do, but I'd rather not have to rely on hard copies of them all.
